# Can not deserialize ArrayList

Tags: android, jackson

I'm using the Jackson library to parse a local json file.
When pushing on parsing button i have that error:

```
W/System.err(7569): org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_NUMBER_INT token
```

The json file is:

```
{"surveys":[{"id_survey":"1","question_survey":"Are you happy with the actual government?","answer_yes":"50","answer_no":"20"}],"success":1}
```

The method that makes the retrieve is:

```
final void gettingJson() {
    final Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
        usersController.init();
        final StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("user : ");
        for (User u : usersController.findAll()) {
            str.append("\n").append("ID : ").append(u.getId_survey());
            str.append("\n").append("Question : ").append(u.getQuestion_survey());
            str.append("\n").append("Yes : ").append(u.getAnswer_yes());
            str.append("\n").append("No : ").append(u.getAnswer_no());

        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    displayJson.setText(str.toString());
                }
            });

        }
    };
    checkUpdate.start();
    }
```

Is there something to add in code? Am i doing something wrong?
Thank you for you help.

Comment: Your question would not be answerable without matching class definition: all that can be said is that Class in question is expecting a `List`, but JSON contains a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, it was due to that string in the json file `"success":1`. So i removed it and now all is fine.

Comment: Yep, this is caused by invalid JSON.  I commonly use a quick PHP script to generate my JSON so I know it's valid.